# Thread-safe linked list with fine grained locks

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost, linked-list

In a program I have a class M:

```
class M{
    /*
      very big immutable fields
    */
    int status;
};
```

And I need a linked-list of objects of type M.

Three types of threads are accessing the list:

- Producers: Produce and append objects to the end of the list. All of the newly produced objects have the status=NEW. (Operation time = O(1))
- Consumers: Consume  objects at the beginning of the list. An object can be consumed by a consumer if it has status=CONSUMER_ID. Each of the consumers keeps the first item in the linked-list that it can consume so the consumption is (amortized?) O(1)(see note below).
- Destructor: Deletes consumed objects when there is a notification that says the object has been consumed correctly (Operation time = O(1)).
- Modifier: Changes the status of the objects based on a state diagram. The final status of any object is the id of a consumer (Operation time = O(1) per object).

The number of consumers is less than 10. The number of Producers may be as big as a couple of hundreds. There is one modifier.

**note**: The modifier may modify the already consumed objects and thus the stored items of consumers may move back and forth. I did not find any better solutions for this problem (Although, the comparison between objects is O(1), the operation is no more amortized O(1)).

The performance is very important. Therefore, I want to use atomic operations or fine-grained locks (one per object) to avoid unnecessary blocking.

My questions are:

1. Atomic operations are preferred because they are lighter. I guess I must use locks for updating the pointers in destructor thread only and I can use atomic operations for handling contention between other threads. Please let me know if I am missing something and there is a reason that I cannot use atomic operations on status field.
2. I think I cannot use STL list because it does not support fine-grained locks. But would you recommend using Boost::Intrusive lists (instead of writing my own)?  [Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html) it is mentioned that intrusive data structures are harder to make thread-safe? Is this true for fine-grained locks?
3. The producers, consumers and destructor would be called asynchronously based on some events (I am planning to use Boost::asio. But I don't know how to run the modifier to minimize its contention with other threads. The options are:

   - Asynchronously from producers.
   - Asynchronously from consumers.
   - Using its own timer.

Any such call would operate on the list only if some conditions hold. My own intuition is that there is no difference between how I call the modifier. Am I missing something?

My system is Linux/GCC and I am using boost 1.47 in case it matters.

Similar question: [Thread-safe deletion of a linked list node, using the fine-grained approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088155/thread-safe-deletion-of-a-linked-list-node-using-the-fine-grained-approach)

Comment: First off, why do you need a destructor? If a consumer correctly consumes an object after dequeueing it, it can destroy the object itself.  If there is an error of a type that allows some sort of later retry, it can set the status appropriately and push it back onto the list.

Comment: I would throw out the idea of having three lists, for simplification.  One for Producer->Modifier, one for Modifier->Consumer, one for Consumer->Destructor.  I'd think it would simplify the code, if not the locking.

Comment: I would be tempted to allow the modifier to lock the entire list for the brief time taken to extract its target object from the list.  It can then do its modification without interference from other entities and then load the object back on.

Comment: @Martin. Thanks for the answer. I need a destructor because after  consumption,the object may or may not be scheduled to be re-consumed. I cannot insert an object again because the order 
of the inserted objects are important (they are sorted initially).

Comment: @Mooding Thanks for the answer. The same reason prevents using more than one list. Each list should be kept sorted and I cannot insert an object in the middle of another list in O(1).
In summary, there cannot be any re-insertion of any object.

Answer (score 9):

> The performance is very important. Therefore, I want to use atomic operations or fine-grained locks (one per object) to avoid unnecessary blocking.

This will make performance worse by increasing the probability that threads that contend (access the same data) will run at the same time on different cores. If the locks are too fine, threads may contend (ping-pong data between their caches) and run in slow lock step without ever blocking on a lock, causing terrible performance.

You want to use coarse enough locks that threads that contend over the same data block each other as soon as possible. That will force the scheduler to schedule non-contending threads, eliminating the cache ping-ponging that destroys performance.

You have a common misconception that blocking is bad. In fact, contention is bad, because it slows cores down to bus speeds. Blocking ends contention. Blocking is *good* because it de-schedules contending threads, allowing non-contending threads (that can run concurrently at full speed) to be scheduled.

Comment: Having a single standard OS lock for the queue should work fine, assuming only linked list operations (point assignments) are done under the lock.

Comment: I want to use fine-grained locks to avoid contention. Each of the threads have some targets and would not touch other objects. For example, each consumer is just interested in the objects which are assigned to it. Using a coarse lock, will prevent all consumers (and modifiers and producers) from operating on their targets.
I know using fine-grain locks has some draw-backs but the benefits are far more, specially in the described situation.

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem with spinlocks where the number of ready threads approaches or exceeds the number of cores because of spinlock contention.  Saves me the bother :)  With this kind of complex requirement, I would certainly want to get the system working in a functionally correct manner first, using kernel locks, with a heavy load test.

Comment: @Shayan: You probably need to separate locks that protect objects from locks that protect collections.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already planning to use Boost Asio, then good news! You can stop writing your custom asynchronous producer-consumer queue right now.

The Boost Asio `io_service` class is an asynchronous queue, so you can easily use it to pass objects from producers to consumers. Use the `io_service::post()` method to enqueue a bound function object for asychronous callback by another thread.

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service_;

void produce()
{
    M* m = new M;
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(&consume, m));
}

void consume(M* m)
{
    delete m;
}
```

Have your producer threads call `produce()`, then have your consumers threads call `io_service_.run()`, and then `consume()` will be called back on your consumer threads. Instant producer-consumer!

Plus, you can enqueue all kinds of other heterogeneous events into the `io_service_` to be handled by your consumer threads if you like, such as network reads and waiting for signals. Boost Asio is more than just a network library-- it's also an easy way to express a proactor, reactor, producer-consumer, thread-pool, or any other kind of threading architecture.

***EDIT***

Oh, and one more tip. Don't make separate pools of dedicated producer threads and dedicated consumer threads. Just make one thread for each core available on your machine (4 core machine => 4 threads). Then have all those threads call `io_service_.run()`. Use the `io_service_` to asynchronously read stuff to produce, from files or the network or whatever, then use the `io_service_` again to asynchronously consume whatever was produced.

That's the most performant threading architecture. One thread per core.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am planning to use io_service for asynchronously running the tasks and what I said in the model is just an abstraction. However, the problem (feature) with io_service is that it does not protect concurrent execution of the tasks (unless we use strands). Therefore, we need the synchronization even when we are using io_service.

Comment: Yes, exactly, use `io_service::strand` if you need to guarantee ordering for async events on an `io_service` for which `io_service::run()` is being called by more than one thread. You've clearly looked at boost::asio already, and I think you should look even more closely. I can almost promise that you'll find that Christopher Kohlhoff  has already thought of every problem that you're likely to encounter with a producer-consumer queue, and has provided a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As @David Schwartz fairly noted, blocking is not always slow and spinning (in user space multithreaded applications) can be quite dangerous.

Moreover, linux pthread library has "smart" implementation of pthread_mutex. It's designed to be "lightweight", i.e. when a thread tries to lock already acquired mutex, it spins some time making several attempts to get the lock before it blocks. Number of attempts is not big enough to harm your system or even break real-time requirements (if any). Additional linux specific feature is so-called [fast user space mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex) (FUTEX), which reduces number of syscalls. The main idea is that it'll do mutex_lock syscall only when a thread *really* needs to block on a mutex (when a thread locks unacquired mutex, it doesn't do a syscall).

Actually in most cases you don't need to reinvent the wheel or introduce some very specific locking techniques. If you have to, then either something wrong with design or you're dealing with highly concurrent environment (for the first sight 10 consumers don't seem that and all these seem like over engineering).

- If I were you I'd prefer to use conditional variable + mutex protecting the list.
- Another thing I'd do is to go over the design again. Why use one global list when consumer needs to do a search to find out whether the list contains the item with its ID (and if so, remove/dequeue it)? May be it's better to make a separate list for each consumer? In this case you probably can get rid of status field.
- Does read access is more frequent than write access? If so it would be better to use R/W locks or [RCU](http://lttng.org/urcu)
- If I wouldn't satisfied with pthread primitives and futex stuff (and if I wouldn't, I would have proved by the tests that locking primitives are bottleneck, not the number of consumers or the algorithm I chosen), then I'd try to think about complicated algorithm with reference counting, separate GC thread and restriction of all updates to be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you on a slightly different approach to the problem:

Producers: Enqueue objects at the end of a shared queue (SQ). Wakes up
the Modifier via a semaphore.

```
producer()
{
  while (true)
  {
    o = get_object_from_somewhere ()
    atomic_enqueue (SQ.queue, o)
    signal(SQ.sem)
  }
}
```

Consumers: Deque objects from the front of a *per consumer queue* (CQ[i]).

```
consumer()
{
  while (true)
  {
    wait (CQ[self].sem)
    o = atomic_dequeue (CQ[self].queue)
    process (o)
    destroy (o)
  }
}
```

Destructor: Destructor does not exist, after a consumer is done with
an object, the consumer destroys it.

Modifier: The modifier dequeues objects from the shared queue,
processed them and enqueues them to the private queue of the appropriate consumer.

```
modifier()
{
  while (true)
  {
    wait (SQ.sem)
    o = atomic_dequeue (SQ.queue)
    FSM (o)
    atomic_enqueue (CQ [o.status].queue, o)
    signal (CQ [o.status].sem)
  }
}
```

A note to the various `atomic_xxx` functions in the pseudo code: this
does not necessarily mean using atomic instructions like CAS, CAS2,
LL/SC, etc. It can be using atomics, spinlocks or plain mutexes. I
would advice implementing it in the most straighforward way
(e.g. mutexes) and optimizing it later if it proves to be a
performance issue.